Unique or single line records in a saved search
I'm working on the work order search feature to show the date and approver when a logo is marked as ready. Each work order can have between 1-4 logos. Right now, my search results are giving me a separate line for each logo approval.
How can I get all the approvals displayed in a single row instead of multiple lines in a NetSuite saved search? Any tips on how to get unique records?

If you post examples of the raw data and the expected/desired results, that will make it easier to help you.  For example: what do you want to see if a WO has multiple logos, of which there are some approved and some not approved?
